# ¿Como agregar columnas a una vista en mysql?

Tags: mysql, vistas

Quiero hacer que una vista contenga unas 9 columnas aproximadamente, hasta ahora solo es sencilla con una sola columna

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que pasa es que tengo calificacion_podcast y calificacion_articulos y los tengo en diferentes vistas, pero me gustaría unirlas en esa misma para solo separarla por columnas y no por views

Mi código es el siguiente

```
CREATE  VIEW `calificacion_videos2`  AS  select (sum(`calificacion`.`calificacion`) / count(0)) AS `cal_video_ovni` from `calificacion` where (`calificacion`.`Tipo` = 'video' and `calificacion`.`categoria` = 'Ovni') ;
```

Eso solo me trae una sola columna, me gustaría saber como hacer que mi vista contenga varias columnas.

Esta es la tabla de donde hago la vista y me baso en el tipo de atributo que es y en la categoría de dicho atributo y dependiendo de la categoría y el atributo es como se debería de hacer cada diferente columna.

Ejemplo
una columna para asesinos otra para creppys y otra para leyendas asi hasta completar las 9 columnas de la vista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿La vista sólo tiene una fila?

Comment: la vista es en base a dos columnas de la tabla a la que se accede aunque si solamente debería de haber una fila por columna

Comment: Entonces la nueva vista tendrá una única fila con diferentes columnas que se calculan independientemente, ¿es eso así?

Comment: exacto, eso es lo que me gustaría realizar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es que tu vista tenga varias columnas independientes, lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE VIEW miVista AS SELECT
    (SELECT .... FROM ....) AS columna1,
    (SELECT .... FROM ....) AS columna2,
    ...
    (SELECT .... FROM ....) AS columnaN;
```

En tu caso, sería algo como esto:

```
CREATE  VIEW `calificacion_videos2` AS  SELECT
   (SELECT (sum(`calificacion`.`calificacion`) / count(0)) from `calificacion` where (`calificacion`.`Tipo` = 'video' and `calificacion`.`categoria` = 'Ovni')) AS cal_video_ovni,
   (SELECT (sum(`calificacion`.`calificacion`) / count(0)) from `calificacion` where (`calificacion`.`Tipo` = 'video' and `calificacion`.`categoria` = 'Misterio')) AS cal_video_misterio,
   (SELECT (sum(`calificacion`.`calificacion`) / count(0)) from `calificacion` where (`calificacion`.`Tipo` = 'video' and `calificacion`.`categoria` = 'Leyendas')) AS cal_video_leyendas;
```

Eso creará una vista con una sola fila y tres columnas (una para Ovni, otra para Misterio y otra para Leyendas) con los cálculos para cada una de ellas. Sólo tendrías que extenderlo al resto de categorías que tengas:

```
cal_video_ovni  | cal_video_misterio  | cal_video_leyendas
----------------+---------------------+--------------------
6.3             | 6.2                 | 7.3
```

Pero casi te diría que si lo que quieres es obtener la calificación por categoría, quizás sería mejor cambiar cómo se crea el view para que haga los cálculos para todas las categorías de golpe (usando `GROUP BY`), lo único es que en lugar de ser 1 fila con 9 columnas, serían 9 filas con 2 columnas (categoría y el valor calculado):

```
categoria       | calificacion
----------------+---------------------
Ovni            | 6.3                 
Misterio        | 6.2
Leyendas        | 7.3
```

Sería algo como esto (no lo he probado y puede contener algún error):

```
CREATE  VIEW `calificacion_videos2` AS  
SELECT   categoria, (sum(`calificacion`.`calificacion`) / count(0)) 
FROM     `calificacion` 
WHERE    `calificacion`.`Tipo` = 'video' 
GROUP BY `calificacion`.`categoria`
```